# I can't override the node template

Tags: 8, theming, nodes, bootstrap-theme

I have installed [Barrio Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_barrio) (`8.x-4.33`) and it worked so far.
But I can't override a template for a specific node type.
I copied the original template into my `subtheme/template` folder and named it like suggested in the FILE NAME SUGGESTION (debug mode).
E.g.: `bs-2col-bricked--node-cuba-casa-particular-full.html.twig`

This doesn't work.

Only when I name it like the original file `bs-2col-bricked.html.twig` it works.

I tried also `5.1.4`, but it's the same. Anything wrong with the FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS?

In my Bootstrap3 theme it worked.

Can anybody help, please.

Comment: Did you enable [Twig debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates) and can you see the template suggestions printed as HTML comments when you inspect the markup?

Comment: Yes Twig debugging is enabled and I see the comments in the source code.

    A bit of light:

It seems so, that I only can override the "basic" templates. I tried with node.html.twig and this worked with node--cuba-casa-particular--full.html.twig    
Display suite and Bootstrap Layout templates doesn't, although FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS show suggestions.
I guess, this is because Bootstrap 4 doesn't work with DS and Bootstrap Layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to turn off the layout ('Manage display' --> 'Select a layout' --> 'none').
Now the debug mode FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS showed the correct suggestions.
I was able to override the 'node.html.twig' in my subtheme (in my case with 'node--CONTENT-TYPE--full.html.twig')from 'themes/bootstrap_barrio/templates/content/'.

Neither the FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS for the DS (8.x-3.9) nor the Bootstrap Layouts (8.x-5.2) were working (the one you see in debug mode, when one of those layouts is selected in 'Manage display').

Maybe there is a better way ...